How to identify from which location a binary(.dll) is trying to read it's endpoints information?
I’m working with a class library named ServiceRef.dll that includes a WCF service reference. This library is utilized across various parts of our application, such as web applications and other class libraries. It contains necessary <bindings> and <client endpoints> for the WCF service.
For the web application, we’ve added the required <bindings> and <client endpoints> to the Web.config file. Similarly, for other class libraries that reference ServiceRef.dll, we’ve included the same configuration in their respective app.config files (e.g., abc.dll.config for abc.dll).
While the web application hosted on IIS can successfully invoke the WCF service using the endpoint information from Web.config, attempting to do the same from a console library results in the following error:

“Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
‘Service.IService’ in the ServiceModel client configuration section.
This might be because no configuration file was found for your
application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract
could be found in the client element.”

Despite trying various configurations and adding endpoint information to multiple config files for different class libraries, the issue persists.
I’m at a loss to determine which config file the binary is attempting to read for the endpoint information. Is there a way to trace how a binary reads its config/endpoints information when dealing with a class library that has multiple config files? Can this process be logged or captured through tools like Fusion log, Event Viewer, or IIS logs?
Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

FWIW, the default location for WCF endpoint configuration for a console app is the app.config for the application.

Yes, as part of build output it generated a config file like as assembly name (e.g., abc.dll.config for abc.dll) but in our case this abc.dll is not reading endpoints information from abc.dll.config file.

For an executable, WCF will (attempt to) read the configuration from the main executable config, not from a dll config.

In our case it's not a executable, it's class library. Even I tried by adding following config entries in main config file, but no luck.  Basically I wanted to understand which config file the binary is attempting to read for the endpoint information. Is there is way to track it out, any traces?

The WCF code is hosted in a class library, I get that. You say above from a console library, which led me to believe you were running an application that referenced your class library. If it's not that, and not IIS, what exactly is loading the library - what has a reference to it?

Let me clarify, we have a WCF service (IService.SVC) & we referred this service inside a class library (ex abc.dll). We added abc.dll as a reference in other Web Application (ex. WEBApp - hosted in IIS) & other class library (ex xyz.dll) indirectly WEBApp calling this class library. Now we were able to invoke WCF operations via Web application as it's reading binding & endpoints information from Web.config. But not from class library (xyz.dll) even though we added required binding & endpoints information in both abc.dll.config & xyz.dll.config files. Hope I'm not confusing you.

I would still think WCF should be looking in web.config in that scenario, since IIS is the application host, so if that's not happening, I'm stumped.

Yes, it's not reading it from web.config. That's where I'm clueless.
By the way any chance to track how the binary attempting to read for the endpoint information.

I have a question, is Console App's app.config is the same file as abc.dll.config? This is the file configured for a specific DLL like abc.dll. Rather, app.config is the main configuration file of the application.  You check that the two profiles are consistent.

Hi @QIYou, Yes, class library config file same as binary name (binary name is abc.dll and config file is abc.dll.config). Also I tested it by placing app.config as well but it's not reading at all.

The first thing I want to say is that the web application project is a web.config file. The console project is an app.config file. The missing thing in your question should look like this:
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50833/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

I suggest you check your app.config file to see if you have the above code, which you can copy from the web.config file of your web application project.

Yes, I have same code in my web.config and app.config (abc.dll.config) files but it's recognizing in web.config entries but not in app.config (abc.dll.config) entries when I tries to invoke WCF service via abc.dll class library.
Basically I wanted to understand which config file the binary is attempting to read for the endpoint information. Is there is way to track it out?

Configuring Tracing
